# How to use "fetchWithRecordID" for automatically generated ID in CloudKit Dashboard?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm new to CloudKit and iOS development. I've manually added some records to the CloudKit Dashboard, and now I want to retrieve them by their IDs, which were automatically created. And then I want to display a record's value in a UILabel for a static tableview cell.  Having two issues: 1). I'm getting an error in xCode when using the ID from the dashboard (error says "expected "," separator") ; and 2). I can't find any examples of putting a record value in a UILabel in a static tableview cell. (especially for swift). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    publicDB.fetchRecordWithID (f7080e7a-f8c3-4db6-b8ee-642a011a6762) { record, error in


        if error != nil {

            println("there was an error \(error)")

        } else {

            // this is my UILabel in a static tableview. The record's only attribute is //called "subCategory"

            plasticOneValue.text = record["subCategory"]
        }   
    }
}
```

UPDATE: ALTERNATIVELY - I tried this code and the build succeeded, but console said it had an internal error and the UILabel was still blank......Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong with the above code or this code?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // I created a new CKRecord ID Object and provided the existing ID in dashboard and //it fixed the error about requiring a "," separator

   var plasticOneID = CKRecordID(recordName: "f7080e7a-f8c3-4db6-b8ee-642a011a6762")

    publicDB.fetchRecordWithID (plasticOneID) { record, error in

        if error != nil {

            println("there was an error \(error)")

        } else {

            self.plasticOne.text = (record.objectForKey("subCategory") as String)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are 2 different issues

1. when querying an ID, you have to query for a CKRecordID as you did in the 2nd sample
2. When accessing the UI, you have to do that on the main queue.

So then the code would be something like:

```
publicDB.fetchRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: "f7080e7a-f8c3-4db6-b8ee-642a011a6762"), completionHandler: {record, error in
    if error != nil {
        println("there was an error \(error)")
    } else {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            self.plasticOne.text = (record.objectForKey("subCategory") as String)
        }
   }
})
```

Comment: When I try your code I still get this error, so I must be doing something else wrong - "there was an error <CKError 0x7facda201b30: "Internal Error" (1/2005)>" 
I also have this code -

`import UIKit
import CloudKit

let myContainer:CKContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
let publicDB: CKDatabase = myContainer.publicCloudDatabase
let privateDB: CKDatabase = myContainer.privateCloudDatabase

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var plasticOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var plasticTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var plasticThree: UILabel!`

@EdwinVermeer

Comment: Thanks for the extra info about queue. I'm still learning. Do I need to call that NSOperationQueue.mainQueue everytime I either fetch, save or update data in the UI?  And what circumstances would I use the background queue? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: All callback blocks are always called on a separate queue. If you manipulate the user interface, then you need to do that on the main queue. Are you sure that the record with that ID is in your public database? The error code 2005 is strange. Are you using the same iCloud account on your device as you developer account? maybe that RecordID is in the private DB and you are querying the publicDB?

Comment: the record is in the publicDB default zone. And I'm using the simulator. Still getting that error. Any other thoughts? Newbie question here, but what is a callback block and when is it used?  Thanks again! @EdwinVermeer

Comment: the completionHandler parameter in the fetchRecordWithID is often called a callback block. The fetchRecordWithID will execute the code in a separate thread (queue) so that your application won't lock during the fetch. The moment the fetch is ready it will call the code in the completionHandler. Since that is still done in the background thread, you need to execute an other block of code on the main queue. That is why the addOperationWithBlock is there.

Comment: Thanks Edwin for explaining. Is NSOperation something that is mainly used when communicating with a network (or cloud) to get data outside the client? Would it also be used for other things, such as receiving a push notification after subscribing to changes in the DB?

Comment: The moment an operation takes some time to complete (like calculations or network activity or massive data processing), it is usually executed on a separate queue in order to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: your code worked...sort of embarrassing, but I didn't realize I had the iCloud setting un-checked for a few days. Thanks again!