# CKAccountStatusCouldNotDetermine and "Internal Error" (1/2005) when trying to connect to CloudKit

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm trying to get the very basics of CloudKit working, but am having trouble. When I perform the following,

```
[[CKContainer defaultContainer] accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:^(CKAccountStatus accountStatus, NSError *error) { }];
```

I get account status `CKAccountStatusCouldNotDetermine` and a `CKError` with a description like

`<CKError: "Internal Error" (1/2005)>`

I’ve tried these things:

- Using different iCloud accounts
- Using different devices
- Turning iCloud on / off in Settings on each device
- Completely resetting my device
- Deleting my provisioning profile and creating new ones, including using a new bundle ID / App ID
- Turning iCloud on / off in the "Capabilities" tab of my target
- Using a completely new iCloud container that was never used with iCloud Drive

Xcode thinks everything is fine. I was previously using iCloud Drive (Documents) using a similar set up and things were fine.

Am I missing something totally obvious?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261948/how-to-use-fetchwithrecordid-for-automatically-generated-id-in-cloudkit-dashbo

Comment: Sorry @MidhunMP but I don't think that question or answer answers my question. I'm not having an issue updating the UI on the main thread, and I'm not trying to fetch a `CKRecord`. I'm merely trying to find out if CloudKit is available at all. From the documentation: "This method determines the status of the current user’s iCloud account asynchronously, reporting the results to the block in the completionHandler parameter. Call this method *before accessing the private database* to determine whether that database is available."

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I read the comments on that answer, and I think it'll help you also. Please check those comments too.

Comment: I saw that question before posting mine. I don't see how it's at all relevant, unless I simply hadn't checked iCloud in my Capabilities tab in my target. Since I stated that I have checked that in my question I don't see how this link is useful.

Comment: I've reformatted my post to make it more clear what I've already tried.

Comment: If that not helped leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was using a separate `.entitlements` file for debug versus production builds, for whatever reason.